# Remember output config when connected to Bluetooth

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones, headset

Everytime I connect to my bluetooth headphones I have to change the Sound > Output configs to `High Fidelity Playback` as the default is `Headset Head Unit`

[image]

Is there a way where the changes I make will be remembered by the system and I won't have to set them manually every time I connect to my headphones (or any device)?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you are using?

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS